# Telegram user api

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I have a task to communicate with someone else's bot in Telegram by making requests. Is it possible somehow to send messages, press keys inline through requests and receive a response?
p.s. not having a bot api key
Selenium doesn't quite suit me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with bots, nor the Bot API, and neither by logging in as a bot with MTProto. You should use a library like [Pyrogram](https://github.com/pyrogram/pyrogram) and login as a user to do that.